# How to escape a $-sign in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I am trying to write a dockerfile in which I add a few java-options to a script called envvars.
To achieve that I want to append a few text-lines to said file like so:

```
RUN echo "JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${CERT_DIR}/${HOSTNAME}_truststore.jks" >> ${BIN_DIR}/envvars
RUN echo "JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${PWD_TRUSTSTORE}" >> ${BIN_DIR}/envvars
RUN echo "export JAVA_OPTS" >> ${BIN_DIR}/envvars
```

The issue here is, that I want the misc. placeholders ${varname} (those with curly braces) to be replaced during execution of the docker build command while the substring '$JAVA_OPTS' (i.e. those without braces) should be echoed and thus added to the envvars file verbatim, i.e. in the end the result in the `/usr/local/apache2/bin/envvars` file should read:

```
...
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/local/apache2/cert/myserver_truststore.jks
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=my_secret
export JAVA_OPTS
```

How can one escape a $-sign from variable substitution in dockerfiles?
I found hints to use \$ or $$ but neither worked for me.

In case that matters (which I hope/expect not to): I am building the image using "Docker Desktop" on Windows 10 but I would expect the dockerfile to be agnostic of that.

Answer (score 5):

first you need to add this # escape=` to your Dockerfile since `\` is an escape charachter in the Dockerfile .  then you can use `\$` to escape the dollar sign in the `RUN` section

Example:

```
# escape=`
RUN echo "JAVA_OPTS=\$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${CERT_DIR}/${HOSTNAME}_truststore.jks" >> ${BIN_DIR}/envvars
```

that will be `JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS` in your env file

Comment: Ah - I had seen this escape mentioned before but hadn't realized it has be defined in a comment, i.e. following an # ! I had first entered it in the file without preceeding # and that only yielded an error message. Your example above clarified that - thanks! Working splendidly - except that in the example above the escape character is ` and in the example you use \. The two have of course to match up, i.e. it has to read # escape=\